# Trouble importing LESS files among different domains

Tags: less

**Warning:** The explanation may be a bit long. In case you are in a hurry, just skip directly to the end of the question, where I summarise what I'm looking for based in my problem.

**Here is the problem:** I have to load a LESS file (from domain A) from another LESS file (from domain B), and build them on real time with LESS.js. Until then, no harm; the instructions in the start of the [official website](http://lesscss.org/) work out of the box.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" ></script>
```

However, there are other LESS files inside B (let's say module1/less, module2/less, and so on), and A should contain the @imports to those files. Also, there are multiple other domains similar to B (C, D, E...). That's where the problem starts. I couldn't find a proper way to do that, considering that I can't update C, D and E (other people need to do it, and for bureaucracy reasons they will only be able to do it after me), only A and B, so A needs to be compatible with the older version of C, D and E (in case they need any change).

When doing an @import inside an imported LESS file, its relative path is according to that same LESS file path, but since that LESS file may be loaded from B, C, D or E, I can't provide an absolute path out of the box.

**What I tried (1):** I surely need to find a way to provide the domain name from B to A. Firstly, I tried by adding something like that before the less.min.js line in the B domain HTML file:

```
<script>
less = {plugins: [{
    install: function(less, pluginManager, functions) {
        functions.add('getRootLessFolder', function() {
            var getDomain = function() {
                return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
            }
            return getDomain() + "less/";
        });
    }
}]}
</script>
```

And then adding that to the start of B's main LESS file:

```
@root-less-folder: getRootLessFolder();
```

So I could update the @imports in A to be like that:

```
@import "@{root-less-folder}module1/less";
```

That approach worked... until I tried using it with the older version of B, before making the changes mentioned above. In that way, LESS claims that `@root-less-folder` is undefined, even if I add `(optional)` to the @import.

**What I tried (2):** I also tried to use the `paths` property in server B, like that:

```
  var getDomain = function() {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
  }
  var lessFolder = getDomain() + "less/";
  less = {paths:[lessFolder]};
```

Because according to the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options-include-paths):

> lessc --include-path=PATH1;PATH2  { paths: ['PATH1', 'PATH2'] }
>
> If the file in an @import rule does not exist at that exact location, Less will look for it at the location(s) passed to this option. You might use this for instance to specify a path to a library which you want to be referenced simply and relatively in the Less files.

So I figured I could use it to make less find the LESS files automatically by just using the line below in A:

```
@import (optional) "module1/less";
```

So it wouldn't find module1/less in server A, but would find it in server B because of the `paths` property. Although, it doesn't seem to try to find module1/less in B. Instead, the Chrome Console spills the 404 error from server A, and the contents of module1/less from B are not present in the produced CSS style (no Console error either), like if it don't even tried.

**What I need:** I need a way to make method 1 or 2 work under those conditions, or even a method 3.

- Being able to populate a LESS variable (if it is not populated **only**) would solve method 1;
- Figuring out how LESS's `paths` is supposed to work may help using method 2;
- Although, maybe you have another suggestion to that problem, which could work out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. In case anyone else is having this trouble, I will describe what I did: apparently, while you can't reference variables that weren't defined, you can reference *plugins* that were not defined (in those cases, they are identified as strings).

So I added that before the less.min.js line in the B domain HTML file:

```
<script>
less = {plugins: [{
    install: function(less, pluginManager, functions) {
        functions.add('getRootLessFolder', function() {
            var getDomain = function() {
                return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
            }
            return getDomain() + "less/";
        });
    }
}]}
</script>
```

And updated the @imports in A to be like that:

```
@root-less-folder: getRootLessFolder();
@import (optional) "@{root-less-folder}module1/less";
```

So when `getRootLessFolder` is defined, the path is based in its returned value, and when it isn't, the path is `"getRootLessFolder()module1/less"`, which will return a 404, but since it's an optional @import, that won't be a problem.

So if server B is updated, the change in server A is going to work. In case server B is not updated, the change is server A won't break it either.